# Split up and unit-test linq-query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Our system is designed to minimize the number of calls to the database by creating the whole resultset in one query.

I am trying to rework the dastardly long linq queries into something that is both easier to read, as well as possible to unit-test the logic of each 'filter', but having some issues figuring out the correct way to use Expression.

Say I have a query

```
return mydbcontext.myusers.Where(<insert a long dastardable linq query here>)
```

that I want to convert to

```
Expression<Func<myusers, bool>> IsInCorrectAgeSegment(int minAge, int maxAge)
{
    return x => x.Age <= MaxAge && x.age >= Minage;
}

Expression<Func<myusersaddress, bool>> HasValidPostalCode(int from, int to)
{
    return x => x.Address.PostalCode >= from && x.Address.PostalCode <= to;
}

return mydbcontext.myusers.Where(x => IsInCorrectAgeSegment(30) && HasValidPostalCode(4600, 5000));
```

But regardless of what I try, I keep ending up with an expection

```
Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Expression<Func<myuser, bool>>' and 'Expression<Func<myuser, bool>>'
```

Is this even possible without first collecting all data and processing it in memory instead?

Comment: While this can be done ([Expression.AndAlso](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.andalso?view=netframework-4.8)), the dynamic composition of expressions becomes atrociously difficult when you start factoring in other logical operations (OR, NOT). The question here is whether you need more than just AND, and whether or not you're willing to commit to this workload because I can tell you from personal experience that this initially seems much easier than it ends up being.

Comment: I'm also questioning the necessity of unit testing these trivially readable filters. Any filter that is sufficiently complex to warrant testing will commonly lead to EF not being able to parse it into SQL anyway.

Comment: It's true that the example are very simple, mostly because I was trying to simplify as much as I could while still retaining the core of it. Some of the parts are way more advanced with .Where().Group().Select().Count() > X.

Comment: It's more trying to split up the query rather than unit-testing it I guess. Right now its about 100 lines, and other queries even longer.